# Commit List as Coordinates for numpy multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I want to commit a list as a set of coordinates for my multi-dimensional numpy array without entering every coordinate seperate. I know it is possible for tuples. Why not for List?

```python
import numpy as np

qn=np.random.choice(list(range(100)), 64).reshape(4, 4, 4)

NS=[1,0,0]

print(qn[1,0,0])
#7
print(qn[NS])
#7   #Would be what I've been looking for

#I also tried
print(qn[iter(NS)])
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "commit a list"?

Comment: You'd be better looking at `qn=np.random.choice(list(range(100)), 64).reshape(4, 4, 4)` as an example so you can see exactly how the array is being indexed differently depending on whether you use a tuple or a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly (i.e. you want to get a single element from `qn` programmatically), all you have to do is to use a `tuple` instead of a `list`.
Note that slicing and list description, although they use the same square bracket symbols `[` and `]`, perform very different operations:

- `item[1]` accesses a portion of the object (depending on the actual object).
- `[1, 2]` generates a list with the elements specified therein.

Hence, in your example, `NS` cannot be used as a substitute of `1, 0, 0` (which is a `tuple`), but explicitly making sure that `NS` is a `tuple` (eventually with the same content as before) would to the trick.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

# FYI, no need to "cast" `range()` to `list`
qn = np.random.choice(range(100), 64).reshape(4, 4, 4)

NS = 1, 0, 0
# equivalent to: `NS = (1, 0, 0)`
# equivalent to: `NS = tuple(1, 0, 0)`
# equivalent to: `NS = tuple([1, 0, 0])` (this is doing a bit more, but the result is equivalent)
# this is different from: `NS = [1, 0, 0]`

print(qn[NS])
# 39
```

If `NS` is generate in some other way as a `list`, all you have to do is to convert to a `tuple` beforehand.

```
NS = [1, 0, 0]
print(qn[tuple(NS)])
```

This is part of NumPy's [sophisticated indexing system](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).